# Angular Compiler looking for html files in NX buildable library

Tags: angular, typescript, build, nomachine-nx

Im new to NX, created a library "designsystem-angular-header" that depends on another library "designsystem-angular"

When I try to build the compiler goes to the dist folder to search for html files for the dependency? Only there are none, only typescript files ... Has anyone had some experience with this?

I have an out of the box Angular 12 tsconfig settings, with the exception of

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

The error is saying in short that it cant find the html files, which I find to be a bit strange that it is looking for those in the first place...

```
nx run designsystem-angular-header:build:production 

Building entry point '@husbanken/designsystem-angular-header'

 Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
ERROR: Cannot read file C:\Users\hoko\IdeaProjects\hb-nx-frontend\husbanken\dist\libs\designsystem-angular\lib\accordion\accordion.component.html.
...
```

[image]
My versions are :
"@angular/cli": "12.0.0",
"@nrwl/cli": "12.3.3",
Node: 12.14.1
npm: 6.12.0

Comment: Do you have @husbanken defined in nx.json?

Comment: @robbieAreBest, thanks for the reply :) No I have "npmScope": "husbanken",  ... tried changing it to "@husbanken", that did not work ... should I have it somewhere else?

Comment: Enabling partial Ivy did the trick "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  }¨, but still dont understand why it was searching in dist for htmls :)

Answer (score 0):

you won't find html files on dist anyway, that's how it is